# i have received google beacon for my business but I can't get them to show up on the beacon tools app

Tags: google-beacon-platform

I have placed my beacons for my business following the directions in the box, activated them using the included link with the activation code, and started a project. I downloaded the Beacon Tools App for iOS but I can't get the beacons to appear in my project or on the app.

Comment: Screenshots might help track down the issue.  You might also use an Android beacon scanner if you have one to make sure the devices are transmitting.  Android devices can see all beacons regardless of identifier

Answer (score 0):

If possible, use an Android device to register beacons in the Google Beacon Dashboard console.

Please note that you will need to be logged in with the account that you want to host your beacons (in this case, I always add a Guest Account to my device so that I can remove it later easily).